# Путь к выбранному файлу из JList

Tags: java

Есть список JList отображающий файлы определенного диска на компе. Выбираю определенный файл или папку

```
File root = new File(list.getSelectedValue().toString());
```

Получаю его имя. Хочу получить полный путь к выбранному файлу на диске вместе с именем.
Пробую так:

```
root.getAbsolutePath()
```

Выдает папку проекта\выбранная папка... Это мне не подходит:(
Подскажите как правильно получить полный путь к выбранному в списке файлу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если этот код дает вам не тот путь, который вы ожидаете:

```
File file = new File(list.getSelectedValue().toString());
file.getAbsolutePath();
```

Еще есть `getPath()` и `getCanonicalPath()` помимо `getAbsolutePath()`.

Попробуйте следующий, с помощью Path API:

```
Path path = Paths.get(list.getSelectedValue().toString());
Path folder = path.getParent();
```

Ссылка на источник:

- [Get the filePath from Filename using Java (path.getParent)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13509864/5275890)
- [Get the filePath from Filename using Java (file.getAbsolutePath)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13509865/5275890)
- [Java File Path, Absolute Path and Canonical Path](https://www.journaldev.com/848/java-file-path-absolute-canonical)

Немного из крайнего источника с переводом на русский:

> `getAbsolutePath()` - возвращает абсолютный путь к файлу. Если файл
>   создан с абсолютным именем пути, он просто возвращает имя пути. Если
>   файл создается с использованием относительного пути, абсолютное имя
>   пути замещается зависящим от системы образом.
>
> В системах UNIX относительный путь становится абсолютным, замещая его
>   текущим каталогом пользователя.
>
> В системах Microsoft Windows относительный путь становится абсолютным,
>   замещая его текущим каталогом диска, названного именем пути, если
>   таковой имеется, а если нет, он замещается на текущий каталог
>   пользователя.

А также:

- [What's the difference between getPath(), getAbsolutePath(), and getCanonicalPath() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1099370/5275890)
- [Getting the Current Working Directory in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7603444/5275890)
- [System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Можно склеить полученный путь и путь к текущей рабочей директории - так получится полный путь, начиная с корневого каталога.

Comment: может ли это не давать абслютный путь из-за того, что список у меня заполнялся так: File[] data = File.listRoots(); JList list = new JList(data); ??

Comment: @TimLeyden вполне возможно. Получается, что возможно происходит замещение как написано в третьей ссылке про `getAbsolutePath()`. Попробуйте для примера наполнить `JList` одним файлом, но при создании его - укажите полный путь и посмотрите результат.

Comment: все верно! Нужно было просто разделить заполнение от отображения. Отображение настраивать в своем рендерере. Спасибо!